# VSCode Node breaking on caught promise as though uncaught

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, es6-promise, vscode-debugger

When running the following code in VSCode, the interactive debugger will break as though it were an uncaught exception. I can continue just fine and running it in Node does not result in an uncaught exception. Is this a bug/limitation of the VSCode debugging environment?

```
new Promise((resolve, reject)=>reject("Exception!")).catch(console.log);
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is a Chromium bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=465666&q=uncaught%20promise%20pause&can=2
Tracked in VSCode: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/116783